TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
Hey Getting this error when using Swiper
here is the error details
 ⨯ TypeError: (0 , react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createContext) is not a function
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./node_modules/swiper/swiper-react.mjs:122:94)
    at (rsc)/./node_modules/swiper/swiper-react.mjs (/media/mazhar/working_material/client-work/new_egala/egalaspot_n-storefront/.next/server/vendor-chunks/swiper.js:410:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/media/mazhar/working_material/client-work/new_egala/egalaspot_n-storefront/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/modules/home/components/hero/index.tsx:7:70)
    at (rsc)/./src/modules/home/components/hero/index.tsx (/media/mazhar/working_material/client-work/new_egala/egalaspot_n-storefront/.next/server/app/[countryCode]/(main)/page.js:808:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (/media/mazhar/working_material/client-work/new_egala/egalaspot_n-storefront/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///(rsc)/./src/app/[countryCode]/(main)/page.tsx:9:87)
    at (rsc)/./src/app/[countryCode]/(main)/page.tsx (/media/mazhar/working_material/client-work/new_egala/egalaspot_n-storefront/.next/server/app/[countryCode]/(main)/page.js:592:1)
    at Function.__webpack_require__ (/media/mazhar/working_material/client-work/new_egala/egalaspot_n-storefront/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:33:42)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  type: 'TypeError',
  page: '/us'
}

And Code:
// Import Swiper React components
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react"
import Image from "next/image"
import "../../../../styles/SlideShow.module.css"
import { Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation } from "swiper/modules"

// Import Swiper styles
import "swiper/css"
import "swiper/swiper-bundle.css" // Ensure correct path to CSS file
import "swiper/css/pagination"
import "swiper/css/navigation"

interface Slider {
  id: number
  image: string
}

const sliders: Slider[] = [
  { id: 1, image: "@public/bg-img/slider2_20240715032150714.jpg" },
  { id: 2, image: "@public/bg-img/slider3_20240715032150854.jpg" },
  { id: 3, image: "@public/bg-img/slider4_20240715032150854.jpg" },
]

export default function Hero() {
  return (
    <Swiper
      slidesPerView={1}
      spaceBetween={0}
      loop={true}
      autoplay={{
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      }}
      pagination={{
        clickable: true,
        type: "fraction",
        dynamicBullets: true,
      }}
      navigation={true}
      modules={[Autoplay, Pagination, Navigation]}
      className="mySwiper cursor-pointer"
    >
      {sliders.map((slider) => {
        return (
          <SwiperSlide key={slider.id}>
            <Image
              src={slider.image}
              layout="responsive"
              width={1144}
              height={400}
              alt="Slide image"
            />
          </SwiperSlide>
        )
      })}
    </Swiper>
  )
}

Guide me on how I can resolve this issue, and let me know if I did something wrong?
Note: already tried remove node-modules and yarn install but didnt get any luck

Probably you can add top of file "use client". This error usually resolved adding "use client" top of file.

just add at the top of your file before imports.
'use client';

